# How to compute the outer product of two binary vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am generating a random binary matrix with a specific number of ones in each row. Now, I want to take each row in the matrix and multiply it by its transpose (i.e `row1'*row1`).

So, I am using `row1=rnd_mat(1,:)` to get the first row. However, in the multiplication step I get this error

> "Both logical inputs must be scalar. To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead."

Knowing that I don't want to compute element-wise, I want to generate a matrix using the outer product. I tried to write `row1` manually using `[0 0 1 ...]`, and tried to find the outer product.  I managed to get the matrix I wanted.

So, does anyone have some ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Take a look at the `size` of your two vectors. They probably have the same orientation, i.e. both row vectors. To take the outer product, you need one row and one column vector. Try using `transpose`

Comment: @2cents, I am transposing one of them before the multiplication.

    row1=VecMat(1,:),
    row1T=row1',
    W=row1T*row1,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix multiplication of `logical` matrices or vectors is not supported in MATLAB.  That is the reason why you are getting that error.  You need to convert your matrix into `double` or another valid numeric input before attempting to do that operation.  Therefore, do something like this:

```
rnd_mat = double(rnd_mat); %// Cast to double
row1 = rnd_mat(1,:);
result = row1.'*row1;
```

What you are essentially computing is the outer product of two vectors.  If you want to avoid casting to `double`, consider using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to do the job for you instead:

```
result = bsxfun(@times, row1.', row1);
```

This way, you don't need to cast your matrix before doing the outer product.  Remember, the outer product of two vectors is simply an element-wise multiplication of two matrices where one matrix is consists of a row vector where each row is a copy of the row vector while the other matrix is a column vector, where each column is a copy of the column vector.

`bsxfun` automatically broadcasts each row vector and column vector so that we produce two matrices of compatible dimensions, and performs an element by element multiplication, thus producing the outer product.

Comment: Great thanks it worked and produced the results that I wanted.

Comment: @motaha - My pleasure.  If you no longer need help, consider accepting my answer.  That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down voting buttons.  This tells the StackOverflow community that you no longer require assistance in this matter.  Good luck!

Comment: OK, I have another question but I am posting it in a new post so many can answer/benefit from it but regarding this issue I am satisfied.

Comment: @motaha - No problem.  Please go ahead and post your question.

Comment: Good `bsxfun` explanation on this!