# for looping with an incremented counter in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 15*15 binary matrix I multiply each row by its transpose to get another matrix from the outer product and then OR these matrices together to get a final matrix. I am trying to do this using a for loop since I have 15 rows and I might increase it to have a large number of rows, so, it is non-sense to do it manually.  For the row by transpose multiplication I am following [rayryeng answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240621/how-to-compute-the-outer-product-of-two-binary-vectors/29240860#29240860). Yet, i want to apply to to the whole matrix. So, I am using the following code.

```
VectMat=randi([0 1],15,15);
resultt=zeros(15,15)
for i= 1:15
    row{i}=VecMat(1,:);
    result{i} = bsxfun(@times, row{i}.', row{i});
    resultt=result|resultt
end
```

I am getting an error and I know that the use of '{ }' isn't correct but if i tried using '[ ]' matlab will consider 'resultt' as an array and will keep adding to it in that manner. My pseudo code is, in the first iteration the 'i' will be one and all of the variables containing '{i}' will be variable number 1 then in the next iteration 'i' will be 2 and so on. So, can I do this on matlab?

Comment: This is a post that you should consider reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877835/efficiently-compute-a-3d-matrix-of-outer-products-matlab - This is essentially the same method that Divakar used in his answer to you below.  Each outer product is placed as a slice in a 3D matrix, and the results are all merged together using `any`, which simulates a logical OR over all of the slices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer using the any(bsxfun...) implementation is much more elegant (and I learned something new with that).  However, with regards to your implementation, this is how you would make it work.  Use

```
for i = 1:15
  row(i, :) = VecMat(i, :);
  result = bsxfun(@times, row(i, :).', row(i, :));
  resultt = result|resultt;
end
```

You can also replace `row(i, :)` with simply `row`.

Comment: If you do it this way, you are creating an inefficient copy `row` of `VectMat`. The line `row(i, :) = ...` is problematic. With every iteration of the for-loop a larger matrix has to be allocated and the values of `row` have to be rearranged, as the storage principle used by MATLAB is column-major. A better approach would be to replace every occurrence of `row(i,:)` in your code by `row`, or even better to replace `row(i,:)` with `VectMat(i,:)` altogether.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to create `singleton dimensions` needed by [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to let the `singleton-expansion` do its work and which would essentially replace your loop. Here's the implementation -

```
any(bsxfun(@and,permute(VectMat,[3 2 1]),permute(VectMat,[2 3 1])),3)
```

Please note that one can use `bsxfun@times` in place of `bsxfun(@and`, but from my experience of working with `bsxfun`, using logical operators (`@and` in this case) could be more efficient.

Comment: This certainly reminds me of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877835/efficiently-compute-a-3d-matrix-of-outer-products-matlab) :)

Comment: @rayryeng Yup, very similar actually!

Comment: Yup. It needs one more step... Using `any` but most of it is that post.

Comment: @rayryeng And the permuting dimensions are different, because OP here wants rows instead of columns in the previous post.

Comment: Wow I forgot to upvote!  Just did it.  Also, I understand.  I realize that I wanted it over columns instead of rows as per the OP, so certainly the permute will be different.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand and I don't understand what are the numbers [3 2 1] stands for and does it relate to my 15*15 matrix or not. I looked for the permute in matlab help and i couldn't see how it might help in my case. Or may be I am the one who don't really get it

Comment: @motaha `permute` works on shifting dimensions and it doesn't relate to the size of `VectMat` but rather just shifts its dimensions. For example, `permute(VectMat,[3 2 1])`, would "make" the rows as the third dimension & "bring" the dimension-3 which is a singleton dimension (length in dimension-3 is 1) as the rows, giving us an array of size `1 x 15 x 15`. Similarly, with `permute(VectMat,[2 3 1])`, we would have `15 x 1 x 15`. Then, `bsxfun` does its magic to give us the final output. Hope that made sense!

Answer (score 2):

Let the linear algebra do the work for you:

```
VectMat = double(VectMat);
out = (VectMat.'*VectMat)~=0
```

This will be faster than using loops or `bsxfun`. Mind that matrix multiplication is not defined for logicals in MATLAB, so you might need to convert to `double` before, depending on how you create your 'binary' matrix. (In the example you provide, `VectMat` is already a double.)

Comment: Smart approach! Since the input array is binary, you need to convert to `double()` I think.

Comment: @Divakar: That's true. The OP's random input matrix was a double, so I didn't think of that!